# How to validate that a string contains only certain characters

Tags: c#

I am working on an assignment for school:

I have passed a string to a mutator and I need to validate that it only contains spaces, hyphens or upper and lower case letters.

The output is always " ".

Can you see what I am doing wrong? Is there a smarter way to do this? I got this way from my instructor but its not working. Here is my code:

```
public void setFirstName(string newFirstName

{

    bool valid;

    valid = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(newFirstName, "^[- a-zA-Z]?$");

    if (valid)

    {

        firstName = newFirstName;

    }

        firstName = " ";

}
```

Comment: You need to wrap your `firstName = " "` in the `else` branch.

Comment: `firstName = " ";` is always executed, whatever the result of `valid` is?

Comment: In regex `?` means "zero or one". You meant `*` which means "zero or any number" (or maybe `+` which means at least once).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need else block.

```
public void setFirstName(string newFirstName)
{
    bool valid;
    valid = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(newFirstName, "^[- a-zA-Z]*$");
    if (valid)
    {
        firstName = newFirstName;
    }
    else
    {
        firstName = " ";
    }
}
```

**Update**

Your regex seems also wrong it needs * for zero or more occurance instead of ?.
**Correct regex** => `^[- a-zA-Z]*$`

Click here to see working fiddle => [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GNvM7M)

Comment: Also, the regex is incorrect.. see my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to RegEx (which I would not recommend if you're still just learning C#), you can use basic string validation with LINQ and the built in [.Net char methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char_methods(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
bool isValid = newFirstName.All(x => char.IsLetter(x) || x == '-' || x == ' ');
```

In this particular case, `All` will check that every element in the array (a string is a char array) matches the predicate provided where every character:

- must be a letter (upper or lower) OR
- must be a dash '-' OR
- must be a space ' '

If anyone of those conditions fail, then the result will be false.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with LINQ, String is an array:

```
Dim hex As String = "3a42X29bc".ToUpper ' Notice mistake

If Not hex.All(Function(q) "0123456789ABCDEF".Contains(q)) Then
    ' Oops, not hex !
End If
```